# 'autoIndexID' is not a valid collection option - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

When I try to run this on my MongoDB:

```
db.createCollection("mycol", { capped : true, autoIndexID : true, size : 6142800, max : 10000 } )
```

I get this:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'autoIndexID' is not a valid collection option. Options: { capped: true, autoIndexID: true, size: 6142800.0, max: 10000.0 }",
    "code" : 72,
    "codeName" : "InvalidOptions"
}
```

I just don't get it... Sorry if it's dumb. :/

Comment: Which mongodb version are you using ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel the version I'm using is 3.4.1  Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`autoIndexId` option has been removed in 3.4 and was already deprecated in 3.2

From [mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19067:

> Deprecated since version 3.2: The autoIndexId option will be removed
>   in version 3.4.

Also, for [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) :

> Capped collections have an _id field and an index on the _id field by
>   default.

Comment: So, what is the new option for what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: You are trying to automatically create an index on `_id` in your collection right ? You don't need any options, an index is already created by default on `_id`

Answer (score 4):

The correct option is `autoIndexId` , you had put  `autoIndexID` .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the option `--convertLegacyIndexes` (you'll need to use a fairly new version of mongorestore though).

That has been working for me for dumps made from mongodb v2.6