# Mongodb collection insert record without id from console

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo console to create a new collection and insert first new record. I do not want autogenerated default id  column to be created. I tried:

```
db.createCollection("myTable", { autoIndexId: false })
```

but it did not worked.

Comment: What version of mongoDB are you using? That option has been removed since 3.4 as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783330/autoindexid-is-not-a-valid-collection-option-mongodb

Comment: I am using mongo 3.4