# MongoDB:createCollection with parameters

Tags: mongodb

I used this comment

```
> db.createCollection("naveen",{capped:true,autoIndexId:true,size:53440099,max:1000});
```

and I got this:

```
{
    "note" : "the autoIndexId option is deprecated and will be removed in a future release",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain more what you want to do with the code, what is the expected result etc?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `autoIndexId` parameter will remove the `note` in the response.

From MongoDB version 3.2, the `autoIndexId` parameter is deprecated when using `createCollection`, hence you are receiving this `note` message along with the `ok` value to make you aware of this.

The `autoIndexId` parameter is removed in version 3.4.

A reply to a comment below is useful in this answer:

> and replaced with what?

[Looking at this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41783524/6193183), [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) and [MongoDB's JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8237) it seems they are pushing for developers to not intervene with auto indexing.

Comment: and replaced with what?

Comment: @rednoyz it was not replaced. [Looking at this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41783524/6193183), [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) and [MongoDB's JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8237) it seems they are pushing for users to not intervene with auto indexing. Appending this explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, MongoDB doesn't need to create a collection, when you insert document MongoDB will automatically create a collection for you, and also generate unique Id for each document!

**Example:**

```
db.createCollection("naveen",{capped:true,autoIndexId:true,size:53440099,max:1000}); //don't
```

*you don't need to create a collection, you just need to insert a direct document,* it's not like SQL, It's JSON.

```
{ name: 'john', ...}
```

**like this, insert document without creating a collection, it automatically generates a collection for you!**

```
db.newYear.insert({ name: 'john', age: 33, year: 2020 });
```

Comment: It will NOT create a capped collection as the question asks